# Open native maps app on iOS from a Phonegap application

Tags: ios, dictionary, cordova

I have a simple HTML5 + Javascript + Phonegap application that shows some contacts information of a store, like its position. My intent is to open through a link the native maps app for the target platform, in order to star a turn-by-turn navigation from the current position. My code looks like this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
            var addMap = 'maps:q='+ global_indirizzo + ',' + global_comune + ',' + global_provincia;
            window.open(addMap , '_system');
        } else {
            var addMap = 'geo:0,0?q='+ global_indirizzo + ',' + global_comune + ',' + global_provincia;
            window.open(addMap , '_system');
        }
```

This works perfectly on Android, but not on iPhone. Any suggestion? Am I missing any configuration step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are the [Maps url schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)

You just need an `<a>` tag with the url

Example `<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino" target="_system">Cupertino</a>`

Comment: try with target="_system"

Comment: I just forgot to whitelist the url. I have another little issue... when I click on the link, on my testing iphone, it opens google maps web app instead of apple's native map app.

Comment: Is the Google Maps app set as your default maps app? EDIT: Nvm, I am thinking as though it is an Android, where you can choose stuff like that. I dun goofed :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html this link works, you can update your post

Answer (score 0):

This link (plugin) is of great help. It opens up the google map app if the user has preinstalled it in the phone or falls back to Apple Maps. Use the launch navigator.navigate in the your openMaps function.

https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator#example-usage

for e.g, I did it like this in my phonegap app.

$scope.openMap = function ()
               {

```
           launchnavigator.navigate(
                                    [$scope.lt, $scope.ln],
                                    [$scope.clublt, $scope.clubln],

                                    function(){
                                 //   alert("Plugin success");
                                    },
                                    function(error){
                                    alert("Plugin error: "+ error);
                                    },
           {
           preferGoogleMaps: true,
           enableDebug: true,
           disableAutoGeolocation: true
           }); }
```

This works like a charm.

Comment: launchnavigator.navigate not called method, using iOS 12.3. Any idea